# How to model account logic?

Tags: cassandra

Say, I want to create an account system. there is a user id, user name, user email and other fields.

I have the following "find_by" scenarios, so I will also have some "find_by" tables such as account_by_name, account_by_email.

When create an account, I need to check whether the name or email has already been used or not.

Considering the restrictions of batch and lwt, how to accomplish the logic above?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the [KillrVideo](https://killrvideo.github.io/) example project.  You can look at the [schema](https://github.com/KillrVideo/killrvideo-data/blob/master/schema.cql) to see how the user tables were modeled, and look at the user [DAO code](https://github.com/KillrVideo/killrvideo-java/blob/master/killrvideo-service-users/src/main/java/com/killrvideo/service/user/dao/UserDseDao.java) to see how users are created using LWT.  KillrVideo also has examples using other programming languages; you will find links to all the github repos on their website.